# 3-way-handshake file transfer

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to transfer file contents between server and client. For some reasons, everything sent appears as VS? on the server side. I included the functions that send the file content

Client.c:

```
void send_file_to_server(struct tcp_hdr tcp_seg, int sockfd){

  char buffer[255];
   char c;
  bzero(buffer, 255);
  int words = 0;
  FILE *fd;
  fd = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  while((c = getc(fd)) != EOF){
    fscanf(fd, "%s", buffer);
    if(isspace(c) || c=='\t'){
      words++;
    }
  }

  write(sockfd, buffer, 255);


}
```

Server.c

```
void get_file_from_client(struct tcp_hdr tcp_seg, int sockfd){


  FILE *fp;
  char buffer[255];
  bzero(buffer,255);
  int ch = 0;
  fp = fopen("file_two.txt", "a");
  int words;

  read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
  printf("%s\n\n\n\n", buffer);
  // while(ch != words){
  //   read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
  //   fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
  // }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rewrite your client.

1. `write(sockfd, buffer, 255);` sends garbage, because not all strings are 255 character long, and you're reading string from the file using `fscanf()`. This is probably where all your "VS" comes from.
2. `getc(fd)` makes your client to skip a character once in a while.
3. your word counting routine is clearly interfering with your file sending code, make it a different loop or separate in some other way.

All in all, I'd start with a simple client that does:

```
write(sockfd, "ABCDEFGH\n", 9);
```

and see if you can receive this on the server side. Then do more complicated stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried hard sending the string and got the same result without reading from file.